# Simple Application to switch Primary dispay

Tags: c#, windows-vista, multiple-monitors

My current set up for my computer is with a 17 inch monitor on my desk and my HDTV a few feet away.  Every once in a while (generally when playing games) things work better when I switch my primary display to my HDTV.  I'm running vista, so things can become a huge pain, as I have to go through several windows just to switch.

I'm thinking of making a simple application that will simply switch my primary and secondary monitors.  I've looked around here, codeprojects and the MSDN library and haven't gotten anywhere.  Anyone know a basic algorithm to switch the monitors in C++/C#?

Comment: You might want to start here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Display_Settings.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know you can just press Windows + P to change the status of your monitors?

Otherwise start here: http://www.news2news.com/vfp/?example=374&ver=vcs

Hope that helps.